# JTable and GUI Query?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

A Jslider with two thumb icons for min and max and two JTextFields to represent there numbers (min and max) are imposed on a JPanel, which is in turn put in a cell of a Jtable of order 3X4.

This Is Gui is only applied for col(0).

The Scenario is this, whenever the the cell is clicked the panel tends to shifts from it's real position and when the mouse is released it return backs to to it's original position. How can this movement be stopped.

Thank You in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add a Border to the panel. The spacing around the renderer and editor component are different.